# Probability of $2$ rolling $2$ coins and a die

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm struggling with this problem:

If I flip $2$ fair coins and rolls a fair $6$-sided die, what are the odds that I will get at least $1$ tail and a composite number

Answer (score 1):

$A,B$ be the events of "get at least a tail" and " a composite number". $P(A) = 3/4, P(B) = 2/6 = 1/3$, use $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)= 1/4$ since they are independent events.